# Running total of consecutive identical values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cumsum

How can I get a running total of consecutive 1's in a pandas Series?

For example, `s = pd.Series([5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4])`. I want to obtain `pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0])`.

(Pandas 0.18.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) comparing `s1 != 1` with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print s1.groupby((s1 != 1).cumsum()).cumcount()
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    0
dtype: int64
```

Better explanation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s1, columns=['orig'])
df['not1'] = s1 != 1
df['cumsum'] = (s1 != 1).cumsum()
df['cumcount'] = s1.groupby((s1 != 1).cumsum()).cumcount()
#s1.groupby((s1 != 1).cumsum()).cumcount() is same as:
df['cumcount1'] = df.groupby('cumsum')['orig'].cumcount()
print df
    orig   not1  cumsum  cumcount  cumcount1
0      5   True       1         0          0
1      1  False       1         1          1
2      3   True       2         0          0
3      4   True       3         0          0
4      1  False       3         1          1
5      1  False       3         2          2
6      2   True       4         0          0
7      3   True       5         0          0
8      1  False       5         1          1
9      1  False       5         2          2
10     1  False       5         3          3
11     4   True       6         0          0
```

Or:

```
print (s1 == 1) * (s1.groupby((s1 != s1.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    0
dtype: int64
```

Explanation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s1, columns=['orig'])
df['compare_shift'] = s1 != s1.shift()
df['cumsum'] = (s1 != s1.shift()).cumsum()
df['cumcount'] = s1.groupby((s1 != s1.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
df['cumcount1'] = df.groupby('cumsum')['orig'].cumcount() + 1
df['is1'] = (s1 == 1)
#True in converted to 1, False to 0
df['fin'] = (s1 == 1) * (s1.groupby((s1 != s1.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)
print df
    orig compare_shift  cumsum  cumcount  cumcount1    is1  fin
0      5          True       1         1          1  False    0
1      1          True       2         1          1   True    1
2      3          True       3         1          1  False    0
3      4          True       4         1          1  False    0
4      1          True       5         1          1   True    1
5      1         False       5         2          2   True    2
6      2          True       6         1          1  False    0
7      3          True       7         1          1  False    0
8      1          True       8         1          1   True    1
9      1         False       8         2          2   True    2
10     1         False       8         3          3   True    3
11     4          True       9         1          1  False    0
```

Comment: I assume it needs one complete pass through the rows for `(s1!=1)`, one for `cumsum`, one for `groupby`, and one for `cumcount`. Does the fact that it needs to make 4 passes slow it down compared to a (hypothetical) pandas method that would do everything in a single pass? (Of course, I know that even with that, it's still much faster than pure-python loop.)

Comment: I think it is faster/nicer because using pandas function, although it 4 times pass.

Answer (score 0):

Not the pretiest way (and likely not the most optimal), but the following gets the job done (and about 4.5x faster than the other looping answer):

```
s = pd.Series([5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4])

def consecutive_n(s, n=1):
    a = s[s==n].cumsum()[s.index].fillna(0) / n
    b = a[a.diff() > 1]
    c = (b.rank() - b)[s.index].fillna(0).cumsum()
    return (a + c).apply(lambda x: np.where(x<0, 0, x)).astype(int)

>>> consecutive_n(s, n=1)
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    0
dtype: int64
```

Some explanation about the intermediate values:
`a`: nth occurence of 1 in the whole series.
`c`: How much has to be added to `a` to "reset" the occurrence count when a different number shows between 1's (or n's).
return value: Applying lambda to ignore negative numbers resulting form `a + c`.

---

EDIT:
Changed slightly the code so it works for any positive integer. Example:

```
>>> t = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1])
>>> consecutive_n(t, 2)
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     2
7     0
8     1
9     2
10    3
11    0
dtype: int64
```